# Reload a javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a PHP file that shows up a session meter for Joomla's frontend using JavaScript. I have also made an other PHP file that shows the user's details and it reloads using jQuery. What I want to do is, when I press jQuery's reload button, JavaScript session meter reload too.

**Session Meter PHP:**

```
<?php // NO DIRECT ACCESS
         defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

         $document = & JFactory::getDocument();
         $document->addStyleSheet('***/***/session_meter.css');
         include('***/***/scripts.php');
         $document->addScriptDeclaration($javascript);

         $output = array();
         $session = & JFactory::getSession();
         $expire = $session->getExpire();
         $output[] = '<span id="log_res" class="">'.$expire.'</span>';

         foreach ($output as $item){echo $item;}
         ?>
```

**Session Meter javascript (part of it):**

```
<?php // NO DIRECT ACCESS
         defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

         $javascript  = ' var timer_start =$time(); '."\n";
         $javascript .= 'blah blah blah...
         ?>
```

**User Profile JQuery script (part of it):**

```
<?php // NO DIRECT ACCESS
    defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>

        <script>        
    var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $JQ_(document).ready(function(){        

    $JQ_("#refresh_button").click(function(){$JQ_("#r_points").load('index.php #r_points').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);});       
        });
    </script>
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$JQ_("#refresh_button").click(function(){
    $JQ_("#log_res").load('index.php #log_res').fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

but it only reloads session meter's `span` and **not** its JavaScript!

Any idea?

Comment: Can't you just call the initiating function in javascript after loading the PHP via ajax? If your session meter javascript is not encapsulated into a function then do that so you can call it later.

Comment: From what you write, I can't even make up how the javascript is loaded in the first place; let alone why it isn't reloaded.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling: In first part of code using this... `include('***/***/scripts.php'); $document->addScriptDeclaration($javascript);`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what can be done with php...but things you can do are:

- Save In local storage (the progress)
- Put reloading part in iframe so parent doesn't load again
- Wrap Js meter part into function and call it at the top/onload event, so when page reloads it gets called too.
- Use `eval` to call javascript that is in string form

Comment: let me know if none of these solve what you want to do..which is unlikely but who knows.